# How do I connect thermostat C-wire to Peerless boiler setup?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I’m having issues getting power to the thermostats over the C-wire.  I have both an HVAC system and an oil burner (Peerless WBV -03 Boiler with a Hydrostat 3250-Plus control module). The oil burner has a wiring relay panel, where I can see the wiring for each zone, as well as the unused C-wire for each zone (green wire). There is a 24V COM terminal on the relay panel that has two terminals (underneath) for connecting wires.  I tried the following to get power to the thermostats, but with no luck.

1. Wire nutted the C-wire (green) at the splice juncture for each thermostat zone.  These wires were not connected to anything prior to me connecting them.
2. Plugged the two green wires (one from each thermostat zone) into the two terminals on the COM terminal.  I have since disconnected them and they are hanging in the picture with electrical tape at the ends.
   When I powered everything back up, I don’t get power or enough power to power the smart thermostat.  Is there anything that needs to be done on the Hydrostat control module side?  I’m not sure what I’m missing here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I hope the uploaded pictures help in illustrating the current wiring setup.

One other note…. At the thermostat, there are two separate wire bundles that come in.  One of the bundles has the green unused wire, which is what I’m trying to use to get power to the thermostat, but the second bundle has an unused blue wire.  I do not see this blue wire anywhere in the boiler wire setup, but I do see it when I go up into the attic where the air handler is.  Does this play into the equation in getting power to the thermostat as well?

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Thermostat Wiring Front]
[image: Thermostat Wiring Back]
[image: Thermostat Zone Splicing Juncture]
[image: Oil Burner Side]
[image: Relay Panel - Thermostat Zones]
[image: Relay Panel COM Port]
[image: Relay Panel]
[image: Hydrostat Control Box]

Comment: Can you post photos of how the thermostats are wired please? Generally speaking, thermostats can only accept a C wire from _one_ of the units they are controlling in a two-transformer setup like yours

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to add additional pictures, as it's telling me I have met the maximum of 8 pictures.  Is there another way I can send the additional pictures?  Should I create a new question with the same title and add them there?

Comment: Ok, I was able to remove a couple of pictures and add the thermostat wiring pictures.

Comment: Could you measure the AC voltage between either R and COM? I would expect around 24-28 V. You could work with the 8 pictures limit by reducing and merging multiple images into a single file before uploading. It appears the pictured thermostat controls one zone of hydronic and also the air handler, while some other thermostat controls the other hydronic zone. Is that correct? Do you know which is zone 1 and which zone 2? What functions does the air handler perform (heat-only, cool-only, or both)?

Comment: At the thermostat side, the voltage is the following: RH and COM (green) is 29.5V,  RC and COM (green) is 0V, RH and COM (blue) is 0V and RC and COM (blue) is 0V.  The picture I include for the thermostat is zone 1 (upstairs) and you are correct, one set of the wires is for the AC air handler and the other is for the Oil burning furnace.  Zone 2 is the main floor.  The air handler is only for AC.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that only the right-side terminal on the oil burner's relay board COM port  generated 29.5V to each zones red wire (picture 6).  The left side was 0V to each Zone's red wire.  I put both C-wires into one port right-side port and now I'm seeing 29.5V at the upstairs thermostat (green wire in the thermostat back picture).  Is it ok to plug both into one terminal?  Will this now work when I connect the smart thermostat?

Comment: @Jim -- what make/model of smart thermostat are you installing?

Comment: Emerson Sensi Smart Touch Thermostat.